# How can I play an Edge animation onclick?

Tags: css, onclick, html5-animation, adobe-edge

I want to have an Adobe Edge animation, which plays after a visitor clicks an ordinary HTML form button. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ball_edge.js

remove:
$(window).load(function() {
$.Edge.play();
});


The HTML file

Add immediately before </HTML>:
<script>
$("#RoundRect1").click(function () {
$.Edge.play();
});
</script>
```